# Did Atlassion build JIRA Query Language (JQL) from scratch?

Tags: search, jira

My company is looking at advanced search and reporting solutions, and are considering (among other options) creating something akin to [JIRA's JQL](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching) for maximum flexibility.

My googling leads me to believe Atlassian built JQL from scratch, at least as a language with syntax and a parser, but I thought I'd try SO before concluding.  Anyone know, at a high level, how they did it?  Was there one or more Open Source project they based it on?

(Kudos to Atlassian either way - JQL is gorgeous!)

Comment: for late comers to this topic;  JQL may not be open source but IntelliJ implemented the [JQL parser](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/tasks/tasks-core/jira/src/com/intellij/tasks/jira/jql/JqlElementTypes.java).  There's formal JQL syntax in the comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think they did it from scratch. The underlying architecture is crisp but quite complex. It took me a good few hours to get it, just reading the source and minimal user docs.

~Matt

Comment: Also, with Atlassian appearing to be so open with their business - blogging about development, for instance - you'd think they'd give some credit to any underlying technologies they used to pull it off if they had.  We use hosted JIRA, so all I see is the UI - thanks for the info.

Comment: Atlassian did develop JQL from scratch. The parser for the language was developed using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). Once parsed, it is turned into the appropriate set of Lucene and database queries, and executed. The ANTLR documentation has a [good, simple example](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Expression+evaluator) of how to parse an expression and then "execute" it. (I'm a JIRA developer, so you are getting the inside story :) )

Answer (score 3):

Atlassian built JQL on top of Apache Lucene. You might want to take a look at Elasticsearch or Solr, which are open source alternatives, also built on Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Jira for a year and I notice "Apache Lucene" on the the directory, and before this I got a job wherein I was force to learn apache solr. So in conclusion, Jira is using Apache Lucene as a searching library which is also used was being used in Solr.

for more info read this: 
http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-vs-solr.html